# Fork child and parent running separate code

Tags: c++, fork, shared-memory

I'm trying to dot product two vectors, with each process taking on a separate starting and ending index. What seems to be happening is that the code gets executed twice.

```
void DotProduct::MultiProcessDot()
    {
    pid_t pID,w;
    int status;   
    unsigned int index = mNumberOfValuesPerVector / 2;

    if((pID = fork()) < 0){
        cout << "fork error" << endl;
    }
    else if(pID == 0){ /* child */
        ProcessDotOperation(0, index);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else{ /* parent */
        ProcessDotOperation(index, mNumberOfValuesPerVector);
        w = waitpid(pID, &status, WNOHANG);
        if(w == 0){
            cout << "alive" << endl;
        }else if(w == -1){
            cout << "dead" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

`ProcessDotOperation` calculates the dot product using shared memory with `sem_wait()` and `sem_post()`. What seems to be happening is this:

- Parent runs `ProcessDotOperation`
- "alive" is printed
- Parent runs `ProcessDotOperation`
- "alive" is printed
- Program continues execution (going on to other functions)
- Child runs `ProcessDotOperation`
- Child runs `ProcessDotOperation`

Note: I may have a fundamental misunderstanding of what's happening, so by `parent` and `child`, I'm referring to the comments in the code as to which process I think is running.

How do I make it such that the child runs `ProcessDotOperation` once, the parent runs `ProcessDotOperation` once, and then the program continues operation?

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit**

If I print before the `fork()`, and change `w = waitpid(pID, &status, WNOHANG);` to `w = waitpid(pID, &status, 0);`, here's the output:

forking

parent

child

forking

parent

child

continued execution...

Here's the code of `ProcessDotOperation`:

```
void DotProduct::ProcessDotOperation(unsigned int startIndex, unsigned int endIndex)
{

    for(unsigned int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++){
        sem_wait(mSem);

        mShmProductId += mVectors[0][i] * mVectors[1][i];
        cout << startIndex << " " << endIndex << " " << i << endl;

        sem_post(mSem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your understanding of how `fork()` works is precisely correct. The code you display should do what you want. You'll need to up your game with respect to debugging. Try printing a line before `fork()` is called. Try printing the arguments and the value of `getpid()` from inside `ProcessDotOperation`. Try printing the value of `pID` before the `wait()` call.

Comment: What's the code for `ProcessDotOperation`?

Comment: *Aside*: Consider using [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) instead of `fork()` and shared memory.

Comment: Try to add a debug printf inside ProcessDotOperation including the caller's PID.

Comment: @Rob, I guess he can't do this in his homework :)

Comment: @Robᵩ I must use processes for this; I've already implemented separate functionality using threading. I print the index in `ProcessDotOperation`, that's how I know who's calling it.

Comment: Would the child process be running `MultiProcessDot` again for some reason? I'm unsure as to how `fork`ing affects classes. Also, printing out `pID` before the wait -- there's two different values?

Comment: Somneone is calling MultiProcessDot a second time.

Comment: Print the value of `getpid()` at the beginning of `MultiProcessDot`, before the `fork()`. This will tell you whether the parent, child, or grandchild is calling it a second time.

Comment: @Robᵩ Oh no, you're right. I thought the template provided by the TA would be error-free. Apparently not. Not sure if it's appropriate, but since you have the solution (without seeing the rest of the code!) to my problem I would accept your answer if you post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone is calling MultiProcessDot a second time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a loop around the `waitpid()`.  As it is written, you wait once, without hanging around for a dead child, returning immediately if the child is not yet dead.  This allows the parent to go on with other activities, of course.

I'm not sure it's a complete explanation of what you observe, but we can't see your trace code.  Print things like the process's PID with each message.